# Access Parent Class without declaring property

Tags: .net, class, inheritance

I know this is a very silly thing to ask, but is this possible?

Says I have this class

```
Class A
{
    string propertyA;
    Public A()
    {
        // do something here             
    }
}
```

Then this :

```
Class B
{
    A classA;
    string propertyB;
}
```

Normally I would do this :

```
B classB = new B();
A classA = new A(); 
B.classA = classA;
```

Is there anyway to achieve something like this :

```
Class A
{
    string propertyA;
    Public A()
    {
        // get or set B's properties 
        // but the problem is this class doesnt have a Parent property 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `B.classA = classA;` since class members are `private` by default!

Comment: I'm not sure what *problem* you're actually trying to solve, but this "solution" isn't what you need.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you can't or won't store a reference in A back to B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve that.

To access another object, you need a reference to it.

If you don't have a reference stored locally, you need a way to *find* or *obtain* that reference.

If you have neither, you can't access it.

Comment: Thanks, so is there anyway to obtain that reference?

Comment: That is something you must know. Have you built a way to obtain that reference? You certainly can't go searching through memory for it. Have you stored the reference to B somewhere where A can get hold of it? If not, then either no, there's no way, or yes, there will be a way once you write it. Again, why can't you simply store a reference inside A? It's difficult to help you when we don't know why this is a solution to your problem. If you could explain what it is that you're doing there might be completely different solutions to this problem.

Comment: I can't change the classes's properties since what I can do is only use them. I guess I'll have to figure some other ways to do that!

Comment: If you can't change the classes, why does A require access to B in the first place? Presumably it already have access to everything it needs, otherwise you will need to change it anyway... or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm working on an existing project, and there are modules  that are fixed,mean we only can use/inherit them, can't modify

Comment: A does not require access to B, just something came up my mind when figuring a way to solve my current problem.

Comment: So store a dictionary that maps which B owns which A, store this separately from both A and B.